# Failed to access Symfony API routes and getting Symfony strating page

Tags: symfony, mamp

I've recently switched to mac and i'm trying to setup MAMP enivrement and a Symfony based API.
The problem for now is that i can't access routes all i can get is the Symfony welcome page.

here is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/syndico-api/public/
 ServerName syndico-api.local
 ServerAlias www.syndico-api.local
 DirectoryIndex /index.php
  <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/syndico-api>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that i needed to add an `Alias` in the  `httpd.config`

`Alias /api "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/syndico-api/public/index.php"`

i can get now to the api by adding /api to the local address.

thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `/public` in your `Directory` instruction:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/syndico-api/public
 ServerName syndico-api.local
 ServerAlias www.syndico-api.local
 DirectoryIndex /index.php
  <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/syndico-api/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As per [Apache PHP-CGI documentation of Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgidocumentation)